# How to call Struts action method while loading the jsp in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Can Anyone share sample code to call action class method while loading a jsp itself.

I need to do some security access control's in on-load of form. struts1 having method called **reset** it will be called each form on-load. same functionality how can i achieve in struts 2.

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: Action -> JSP. Not other way around. You can call action methods in JSP with the S2 tags and OGNL. Security controls should be done in S2 interceptors or use some security framework.

Comment: Before asking for code, show what have you done so far because struts1 is different in architecture and some missing parts replaced by the newer framework struts2. you can learn it before asking questions that looks like nonsense and not clear what have you tried to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create method in action class

```
public String yourMethod(){

//return myString;

}
```

Now on jsp you can use struts tag to call this methd

```
<s:property value="yourMethod()" />
```